Is there a end of week equivalent to EOMONTH() using query?
I want to plot a chart where I can see the issues resolved per month, what do I need to do to have the plot showing issues resolved per week or 2 weeks
Here is my query for getting the issues per month
=QUERY({'Sheet1'!$A$1:$F$2530,ARRAYFORMULA(EOMONTH('Sheet1'!$G$1:$G$2530,0))},
"select Col7,count(Col1) 
where Col6 matches 'bug|customer_issue'
group by Col7 
label Col7 'Created Month', count(Col1) 'Total Bugs created'  format Col7 'MMMM-YY'",1)

I get this



Month
Created issues




January 2024
25


February 2024
31



But I would really like to see weekly or bi weekly breakdown. Any help will be much appreciated

You can use WEEKNUM to get the number of the week in the year (from 1 to 52):
=QUERY({'Sheet1'!$A$1:$F$2530,ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR('Sheet1'!$G$1:$G$2530,0) & "week #" & WEEKNUM('Sheet1'!$G$1:$G$2530,2))},
"select Col7,count(Col1) 
where Col6 matches 'bug|customer_issue'
group by Col7 
label Col7 'Week number', count(Col1) 'Total Bugs created',1)

Output:



Week number (1 to 52)
Created issues




2024 week #1
25


2024 week #13
31



A possible solution to output biweekly results would be to use QUOTIENT to integer-divide the week numbers by 2 (non consistency exists; see comments):
=QUERY({'Sheet1'!$A$1:$F$2530,ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR('Sheet1'!$G$1:$G$2530,0) & "bi-week period #" & QUOTIENT(WEEKNUM('Sheet1'!$G$1:$G$2530,2)+1,2))},
"select Col7,count(Col1) 
where Col6 matches 'bug|customer_issue'
group by Col7 
label Col7 'Biweek number', count(Col1) 'Total Bugs created',1)

Output:



Biweek number (1 to 26)1
Created issues




2024 bi-week period #1
25


2024 bi-week period #7
31




1 Or 27... see comments.
References

YEAR
WEEKNUM
QUOTIENT


The QUOTIENT-based approach to two-week periods has the awkwardness that every fifth or sixth year has an odd number of weeks. This may or may not matter, depending on use-case.

@ruakh Ah. Hadn't thought of that. '52' was hardcoded in my mind as a universal value but it is true that 365.25 % 7 !== 0.
